# DLL Missing from Modules List in VS2010

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, pinvoke

I've really been banging my head against the proverbial wall over this one.

I have a solution which contains both C# and C++ code projects.

I often call the C++ DLLs, which are compiled in this project from the C# via P/Invoke.  No problemo.  All the requisite debugger settings through the *.sln file, as well as the C++ and C# files, have been properly set, to the best of my knowledge.  Note:  I often am able to debug similarly P/Invoked C++ code with no issues!

Naturally, I figured that, perhaps, the symbols weren't loading -- yet, upon opening the modules window, I discovered that the DLL into which I am attempting to step isn't even listed!  Running the function in my C# program does indeed use the DLL (I get the correct output), but, whilst watching the Modules window, the DLL still does not appear.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on?

tl;dr --> I have a fair amount of experience with debugging P/Invoked C++.  However, the DLL I wish to debug does not even appear in the Modules list (so I obviously am not able to step into it if the VS debugger appears to be completely unaware of its existence).

Thanks in advance!!

Cheers!

-Kadaj

Comment: How can we reproduce your scenario?

Comment: Are you set up to do "mixed mode" debugging?  I.e are none of the native (i.e C++ modules) listed or are some listed, just not the one you're trying to debug?

Comment: David:  Unfortunately, I am not able to easily reproduce the scenario, as this is the only time that I have ever had a dll missing from the Modules list!

Matt: I am set for mixed mode debugging within the C++ projects, with Attach set to Yes.  Within the C# project, the C++ projects are listed as dependencies.  Also within the C# project, Enable unmanaged code debugging is checked.  The thing is that, when the code is invoked, even under the Debug > Modules screen, none of the C++ dlls are listed.

Have either of you seen this before?  Thank you for your tips so far!

Comment: The start-up project setting is what important (the start-up project is the one that is bolded in the solution explorer).  Is *that* project's debug settings set to "enable unmanaged code debugging"?  Another thing to try is just to start up the process, and attach to it from the debugger and see if you get different behavior.

Comment: ^This solved it !!  Thank you so much, Matt !  I had incorrectly assumed that only the C# project calling the C++ dll needed to have this setting.  Well, not assumed, per se, but it did not occur to me that, what now seems obvious after you have enlightened me --> the top level C# start-up project (i.e. the *.exe that is run), is what needs to have this flag set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess would be that you do not have debugging turned on for unmanaged code.  Go to the Start-up project's Properties->Debug tab.  Check "Enable unmanaged code debugging".

Comment: Hello, Matt!  Thank you for the tip!  Enable unmanaged code debugging is checked.

Comment: NB:  This needs to be set on the actual start-up project or *.exe itself (which now seems painfully obvious in retrospect, although not so much when attempting to solve it), rather than the particular C# project P/Invoking the C++.