# Crash in C# calling PInvoke

Tags: c++, .net, pinvoke

I have an library written in C++, and I want to call it from my managed C# code.
According to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk9wyw21(v=vs.110).aspx) I should be able to make the following declaration in the managed code:

```
[DllImport("PatternTracking.dll",
        EntryPoint = "tracker",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
        CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern void dukeTracker(
        [In, Out] int[,] imgOrig, [In, Out] int[,] refImgOrig,  //<-Input
        int x0, int y0,                                         //<-Input
        ref double maxCC, ref int xTrack, ref int yTrack);      //<-Output
```

The function signature in C++ is as follows:

```
extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport) void tracker(int imgOrig[NY][NX], int refImgOrig[NY][NX],     //int imgScopeBW_Orig[NY][NX],              //<-Input
    int x0, int y0,//int nx_template,int ny_template,                                   //<-Input
    double *maxCC, int *xTrack, int *yTrack)
```

}

When I call the function, something very bad happens, causing the debug environment to fail:

[image: Error Message]

This seems to be happening during the transition from managed to unmanaged, as a breakpoint set on the first line of the unmanaged code is not hit. In fact, the modules window shows me that the unmanaged DLL is not loaded.

My guess is that there is something wrong with the parameter declarations. [This blog](https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/passing-multi-dimensional-managed-array-to-c-part-1/) seems to suggest that one should treat a multi-dimensional array as a single dimensional array on the C++ side, but that's not what the documentation says. Can anyone see what is causing the crash?

**UPDATE**

It turns out that the interface was fine, and an unhandled exception in the unmanaged code caused the crash. I still don't know why the DLL is not shown as loaded in the Modules window, and why the debugger doesn't reach the breakpoint I set in the unmanaged code.

Comment: show us how what arguments you pass to the unmanaged function. greeting from fellow israeli :)

Comment: It turns out that the exception is a result of something that happens inside the unmanaged code. When I block out the function contents with #if false, the function call succeeds, in the sense that there is no exception thrown. I still don't understand why I can't see the DLL in the modules window, and why the breakpoint is not hit.

Comment: Meta question: should I close this question, since the header at least is based on a false assumption? Should I edit everything to put the focus on why the breakpoint fails to work? Create a new question?

Comment: You should find a more precise title, but otherwise the question is fine. Did you try `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.I4)]` as suggested in the article you linked to?

Comment: And see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234384/dll-missing-from-modules-list-in-vs2010) for the answer to the question about the debugger and DLL listing in modules window.